Z-Order problem while displaying isometric tiles
I have a little problem while displaying isometric tiles in my school game.
The fact is that I suppose everything is ok with my code...
Here is how it's organised:

architecture: MVC + ECS
everything is displayed in my render method of the GameView class
I use bases and vetors to make conversions between the two bases (orthogonal one and isometric one)

Here is the code:
public void render() {
    try {
        final Entity[] entities = this.controller.getEntities();

        // Sort entities by isometric depth
        Arrays.sort(entities, (e1, e2) -> {
            PositionComponent p1 = e1.getComponent(PositionComponent.class);
            PositionComponent p2 = e2.getComponent(PositionComponent.class);

            // Calculate depth as the sum of cartesian x + y
            double depth1 = p1.getX() + p1.getY();
            double depth2 = p2.getX() + p2.getY();

            // Primary sorting criterion: depth
            int result = Double.compare(depth1, depth2);

            // Secondary sorting: cartesian Y coordinate
            if (result == 0) {
                result = Double.compare(p1.getY(), p2.getY());
            }

            // Tertiary sorting: cartesian X coordinate
            if (result == 0) {
                result = Double.compare(p1.getX(), p2.getX());
            }

            // Fallback sorting: hashCode
            if (result == 0) {
                result = Integer.compare(e1.hashCode(), e2.hashCode());
            }

            return result;
        });

        for (Entity entity : entities) {
            // Get position component
            PositionComponent position = entity.getComponent(PositionComponent.class);

            // Convert to isometric coordinates
            Vector isoPos = this.gameBase.mulByVect(
                new Vector2D(position.getX(), position.getY())
            );

            // Debug: print isometric position
            // System.out.println("Isometric Position: " + isoPos);

            // Get texture component
            ImageIcon image = entity.getComponent(TextureComponent.class).getTexture();

            // Create label for the entity
            JLabel label = new JLabel(image);

            // Set bounds based on isometric position
            label.setBounds(
                (int) isoPos.getEntry(0),
                (int) isoPos.getEntry(1),
                image.getIconWidth(),
                image.getIconHeight()
            );

            this.panel.add(label);
        }

        // Revalidate and repaint after adding all entities
        this.panel.revalidate();
        this.panel.repaint();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

However, the tiles are not displaying well. In fact the farthest one are displayed after the closest so it seems flipped...
Do you have any idea ?
Of course if needed, feel free to ask as many questions as you want!
Thanks a lot!

Do not edit your question to include the answer. Instead, post your answer instead or accept an existing answer.

The issue you're facing is likely caused by how you're calculating and comparing the depth of your entities for sorting. Since you're working with isometric tiles, the rendering order should ensure that tiles closer to the screen (or bottom-right) are drawn after tiles farther away (or top-left).
In your current code, you calculate the depth as the sum of Cartesian x+yx+y, but this might not correctly capture the isometric depth ordering for rendering purposes.
This depth can be calculated as
depth =p1.getY()−p1.getX()
depth =p1.getY()−p1.getX(), assuming your isometric transformation aligns with this logic.


// Sort entities by isometric depth
Arrays.sort(entities, (e1, e2) -> {
    PositionComponent p1 = e1.getComponent(PositionComponent.class);
    PositionComponent p2 = e2.getComponent(PositionComponent.class);

    // Calculate depth based on isometric Y-X
    double depth1 = p1.getY() - p1.getX();
    double depth2 = p2.getY() - p2.getX();

    // Primary sorting criterion: depth
    int result = Double.compare(depth1, depth2);

    // Secondary sorting: cartesian Y coordinate
    if (result == 0) {
        result = Double.compare(p1.getY(), p2.getY());
    }

    // Tertiary sorting: cartesian X coordinate
    if (result == 0) {
        result = Double.compare(p1.getX(), p2.getX());
    }

    // Fallback sorting: hashCode
    if (result == 0) {
        result = Integer.compare(e1.hashCode(), e2.hashCode());
    }

    return result;
});




I'm sorry, I answered my own question instead of yours...
The answer is above yours!
And thank's again for your help even if it didn't resolved my problem.

Tile Overlapping:
The this.panel.add(label) continuously added labels without clearing the previous frame. This resulted in tiles being overdrawn incorrectly even when the sort was working. Clear the panel before each render using: this.panel.removeAll();
The correct approach sorts entities by:
Y-coordinate (Descending): Closer tiles (lower on the screen) are rendered after farther ones.
X-coordinate (Descending): If tiles share the same Y-coordinate, sort by X to respect left-to-right rendering order.


Arrays.sort(entities, (e1, e2) -> {
    PositionComponent p1 = e1.getComponent(PositionComponent.class);
    PositionComponent p2 = e2.getComponent(PositionComponent.class);

    // Sort by Y-coordinate (descending)
    int result = -Double.compare(p1.getY(), p2.getY());

    // Secondary sort: X-coordinate (descending)
    if (result == 0) {
        result = -Double.compare(p1.getX(), p2.getX());
    }

    // Fallback: Compare hashCodes
    if (result == 0) {
        result = Integer.compare(e1.hashCode(), e2.hashCode());
    }

    return result;
});



